# Issue with sun.security.util while upgrading to from jdk 1.4 to jdk1.6

Tags: java

I am porting a webapplication written in jdk1.4 to 1.6. While compiling I am getting warnings related to `sun.security` package deprecation. Though I can compile with warnings, I prefer to do a compile without warnings.Also this could become errors in future when using jdk 1.7 version.

Warnings are like

```
warning: sun.security.util.DerEncoder is Sun proprietary API and may be removed in a future release
```

I am ready to change the source code by removing the sun packages and use some third party free package.  For fixing some other issues I have rewritten other parts of code(which uses classes like `sun.misc.BASE64Decoder`) using org.apache.commons.codec .But I couldn't find any replacements for `sun.security.util`.

My server is apache tomcat, so using other server libraries like `*ibm*` won't be feasible.

### Edit

I am using classes including(not limited to) `sun.security.util.DerEncoder, sun.security.util.DerInputStream ,sun.security.util.DerValue,sun.security.util.ObjectIdentifier ,sun.security.x509.X500Name etc`

Comment: You would have to tell us exactly *what* in sun.security.util you are using, and also why these warnings were ignored when the application was written, and every time it was compiled for the last ten years.

Comment: @EJP If I got OP right, the warnings only appeared after using JDK 1.6 so they weren't ignored.

Comment: @stonedsquirrel I doubt that the warnings were not there before 1.6. The warnings could be suppressed but basically in a basic install this warnings appeared since at least 1.2.

Comment: @stonedsquirrel , there were no warnings with jdk1.4 compile( for which the application was originally written) , and no warnings are suppressed.

Answer (score 1):

In fact, `sun.security.util.DerEncoder` is an interface and you could trivially create your own version.  The difficult task would be locating and dealing with the classes that implement this interface.

For what it is worth, the DerEncoder interface defines a single method:

```
  public void  derEncode(OutputStream out)
        throws IOException;
```

The method is supposed to output the DER encoding for `this` to the supplied stream.

DER is an encoding scheme for ANS.1 data.  AFAIK, this interface is internal to the Sun implementation of X.509 certificates and so on.  I suspect that fixing this is not simply a matter of finding a replacement class.  Rather, I think you need to understand the reason why your code is (apparently) using this interface, and then figure out the "correct" way to do what it needs to do.  ("Correct" ... as in using public APIs.)

**UPDATE**

Based on the other classes you are using, I think you need an X500 for Java implementation:

- One possibility is the "Oracle Security Developer Tools Security Engine" (aka "Oracle Fusion Middleware Security Engine").  This appears to be part of the Oracle 10g and 11g product suite, but it may also be available separately.  Link: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23549_01/apirefs.1111/e10674/toc.htm

  As far as I can tell, you can't get this stuff for free.  You can only get it embedded in various paid-for Oracle products.
- Another possibility is the [BouncyCastle](http://www.bouncycastle.org/java.html) X509 implementation.

---

Note that Java 6 is EOL'ed, so you should really be porting to Java 7.

Comment: Thanks for the valuable inputs. The production env is 1.6. Thats why we are first porting to 1.6. For last couple of years we were compiling in 1.4 jdk and deploying in 1.6 live env. ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you really need to get rid of these classes (they're still there in 1.7 AFAICT), you'll probably have to rewrite the entire code with equivalent code from a cryptography library. Try this one:

http://www.bouncycastle.org/java.html